# SSH connection timed out when using a different wifi connection

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to remote access my office pc via ssh but I have met with a connection timed out error.
The strange thing is that I encounter the connection timed out when using my home wifi but am able to connect when using my mobile phone's hotspot.

I have spent hours trying to figure out what is the issue but still unable to use ssh to connect my office pc. I think my router might be blocking the connection but I have absolutely no idea how to fix this.

I am using WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Results when trying to use my home wifi to connect to my office pc:

```
myname@DESKTOP-XXX:~$ ssh -vvv nitrogen   
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020  
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myname/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/myname/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for {CONNECTION_NAME}*
debug1: /home/myname/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for {CONNECTION_NAME}
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *     
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 129.126.125.250 is address        
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 129.126.125.250 [129.126.125.250] port {PORT_NUM}.     
debug1: connect to address 129.126.125.250 port 1818: Connection timed out  
ssh: connect to host 129.126.125.250 port 1818: Connection timed out
```

Output from traceroute

```
traceroute to 129.126.125.250 (129.126.125.250), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets 
1 DESKTOP-A16BBJK.mshome.net (192.168.48.1) 0.518 ms 0.486 ms 0.531 ms 
2 192.168.253.180 (192.168.253.180) 57.011 ms 56.996 ms 56.983 ms 
3 Singtel-ACPlus (192.168.1.254) 95.410 ms 95.397 ms 95.385 ms 
4 bb118-200-31-254.singnet.com.sg (118.200.31.254) 943.759 ms 943.747 ms 1044.329 ms 
5 165.21.193.22 (165.21.193.22) 95.486 ms 95.320 ms 95.460 ms 
6 165.21.193.21 (165.21.193.21) 70.440 ms 68.414 ms 68.395 ms 
7 165.21.138.245 (165.21.138.245) 68.465 ms 7.675 ms 23.166 ms 
8 SN-SINQT1-BO403-ae1.singnet.com.sg (165.21.138.85) 7.568 ms 18.002 ms 19.879 ms 
9 203.208.177.213 (203.208.177.213) 19.788 ms 19.688 ms 19.750 ms 
10 203.208.149.25 (203.208.149.25) 19.894 ms 203.208.172.213 (203.208.172.213) 19.875 ms 19.860 ms 
11 203.208.166.241 (203.208.166.241) 20.381 ms 20.362 ms 20.343 ms 
12 203.208.175.154 (203.208.175.154) 20.362 ms 20.343 ms 19.398 ms 
13 203.208.182.253 (203.208.182.253) 19.380 ms 19.369 ms 147.203-211-159.unknown.qala.com.sg (203.211.159.147) 17.173 ms 
14 129.126.98.226 (129.126.98.226) 20.797 ms 203.208.175.154 (203.208.175.154) 20.740 ms 20.709 ms 
15 * * * 
16 * * * 
17 * * * 
18 * * * 
19 * * * 
20 * * * 
21 * * * 
22 * * * 
23 * * * 
24 * * *
25 * * * 
26 * * * 
27 * * *
```

Thank you and any help will be greatly appreciated

Edit 1:

IP: 129.126.125.250

Port 1818

Edit 2:
Added IP and port in output
Added traceroute

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the office PC and your local PC when connected to your router and when connected to your phone? Please [edit] your question to provide this information. Show the output of `traceroute your_office_PC` in both situations.

Comment: you hide ssh port number, is it different from 22 ? if yes, there might be some filtering on incomming IP adress (that would explain why you can use mobile phone's outgoing IP ). if you are not the IT department, what do they says about it ?

Comment: `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config` please + change the port to a valid range 50000-60000. 1818 is reserved, and you shall not use it.

Comment: please post `ssh -vvv` directly on the IP and port without obfuscating the results then

Comment: Do you use a VPN of any sort (on the Windows PC and/or the phone) to connect to the office network?

Comment: Is the output really `{CONNECTION_IP}` (etc.), or did you replace it for privacy? Please indicate in the question to make clear. Also: Can you ping the office PC?

Comment: Hi, I have added my IP, host and traceroute results. Please take a look

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Hi, i have tried changing the port, still get the same results.